# A little help with regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions, substrings

I am trying to create a regular expression that will generate the following language under the {a,b,c} alphabet:
all words that do not contain the substring "bbc"

I am having a really hard time understanding how to approach this question. I have done several other questions where a certain substring must be excluded, but this one really messes with my logic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The key word you are looking is "complement", e.g., complement of a NFA, complement of a regular language.  That should enable you to solve this in a pretty straightforward way.

Comment: Design a NFA for $\{a,b,c\}^*bbc\{a,b,c\}^*$, make a DFA out of it, complement, read the expression from the automaton. This is in most cases the best way to solve this type of "pattern matching" problem. See other examples [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/designing-a-regular-expression-for-the-set-of-all-binary-that-contain-strings-wi).

Comment: This question is similar to [Regular expression for a string not containing a set of substrings](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14837/regular-expression-for-a-string-not-containing-a-set-of-substrings)

Answer (score 2):

Some things I learnt while learning to answer this type of question:

1. Negation isn't easy to express. There are no shortcuts. The resulting expressions may be far more complex than the expression you would get if negation was a basic operator in the expression language - in which case you could write $\neg(.^*bbc.^*)$, where $.$ is a shortcut for $(a\cup\neg a)$
2. Lacking $\neg$, the only way to say $\neg a$ for some symbol $a$ is to enumerate all other symbols: $\neg a = (b\cup c \cup d \cup \ldots)$. In Unix-like regular expressions, you can of course use `[^a]`.
3. In compound expressions, you can use [left factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_factoring).
   E.g. $\neg(bbc) = \epsilon \cup \neg b\neg(bc) = \epsilon \cup \neg b(\epsilon \cup \neg c) = \ldots$.
   The key insight is that this can be made to work with Kleene star expressions, too; I suggest you invent or look up the details yourself.